# I've been everywhere, man

Tags: riddle, word, grid-deduction

> I am a knight facing a plight 
>   My dearest one of all 
>   Lives in a tower and won’t come out 
>   Unless her name I call 
>   I went to pick her up today 
>   And though my mind was set 
>   To do so, as I went along 
>   I lost my … 
>   Without it now, I do not know 
>   Her name I have to call 
>   There’s no way she will harken to 
>   "My dearest one of all!"
>
> Some things I still remember yet 
>   At five I caught some shade 
>   Went by some ponds, did not get wet 
>   A sequence which will aide: `5311512112600320`

[image]

> The thing I lost (the easier part) 
>   Might earn you some reward 
>   To win the game, I need her name! 
>   Please mend my broken heart...

Comment: I haven't the time to make this rhyme,
or even to make it scan.
But this is without a shadow of doubt
the most entertaining puzzle I've seen on this site so far. Nice one!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From some lines of the poem:

> "I am a knight facing a plight"
>  "At five I caught some shade"
>  "Went by some ponds, did not get wet"
>  and the title: "I've been everywhere, man"

we can figure out that

> we need to make a knight's tour on the given grid visiting the forest as the fifth square and skipping the ponds.

Turns out there's exactly one way to do this.

> [image]

And now, the sequence:

> If we divide the sequence into eight pairs, they can be used as coordinates (taking the upper left cell to be the origin).
>
>  Labelling the squares with A-Z (since *conveniently* there are exactly 26 cells visited):
>
>  `MPAXERI`
>  `BWNQHYF`
>  `OLUD JS`
>  `VC KTGZ`
>
>  The letters at these cells spell out **GWYNLIVA**, which... isn't a name, as far as I can tell. But it's the only choice of coordinate direction and origin that makes any sense, *and* it sounds similar to [Guinevere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guinevere), wife of King Arthur.

Comment: Wow, that's quick, it is her name, you get the tick :)

Comment: @OnlyF This was a nice puzzle! The theme was cute and everything was well-clued -- hope to see more from you!

Answer (score 11):

...And the thing that was lost?

> Alphabet???

Comment: Yep, yep, here's your +1 reward :)

Comment: I wonder if @deusovi left that out on purpose, throwing the rest of us a [bone](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) from his already-consumed meal. :)

Comment: Alternative answer that almost rhymes: Rolodex!